# How to display a Ninja Form on the Wordpress admin pages

Tags: wp-admin

I am creating a Wordpress website where I would like to display a specific form on an admin page which has the ability to store form submissions. I have chosen Ninja forms, but I am open to other suggestions.

I am rendering the form using `echo do_shortcode( '[ninja_form id=2]' );`
However, the form is not displaying on the admin page. I can see there is some markup in the source, but the form is not displayed. I have tried adding all the normal Javascripts to the admin page but with no luck.

The output which is shown in source is:

```
    <noscript class="ninja-forms-noscript-message">
    Notice: JavaScript is required for this content.</noscript>

    <div id="nf-form-2-cont" class="nf-form-cont" aria-live="polite" aria-labelledby="nf-form-title-2" aria-describedby="nf-form-errors-2" role="form">

    <div class="nf-loading-spinner"></div>

</div>

    <script>var formDisplay=1;var nfForms=nfForms||[];var form=[];form.id='2';form.settings={"objectType":"Form Setting","editActive":true,"title":"Commission Request","show_title":1,"allow_public_link":0,"embed_form":"","clear_complete":1,"hide_complete":1,"default_label_pos":"above","wrapper_class":"","element_class":"","key":"","add_submit":1,"changeEmailErrorMsg":"Please enter a valid email address!","changeDateErrorMsg":"Please enter a valid date!","confirmFieldErrorMsg":"These fields must match!","fieldNumberNumMinError":"Number Min Error","fieldNumberNumMaxError":"Number Max Error","fieldNumberIncrementBy":"Please increment by ","formErrorsCorrectErrors":"Please correct errors before submitting this form.","validateRequiredField":"This is a required field.","honeypotHoneypotError":"Honeypot Error","fieldsMarkedRequired":"Fields marked with an <span class=\"ninja-forms-req-symbol\">*<\/span> are required","currency":"","unique_field_error":"A form with this value has already been submitted.","logged_in":false,"not_logged_in_msg":"","sub_limit_msg":"The form has reached its submission limit.","calculations":[],"formContentData":["commission_amount_1589829372049","submit_1589829400950"],"drawerDisabled":false,"ninjaForms":"Ninja Forms","fieldTextareaRTEInsertLink":"Insert Link","fieldTextareaRTEInsertMedia":"Insert Media","fieldTextareaRTESelectAFile":"Select a file","formHoneypot":"If you are a human seeing this field, please leave it empty.","fileUploadOldCodeFileUploadInProgress":"File Upload in Progress.","fileUploadOldCodeFileUpload":"FILE UPLOAD","currencySymbol":"&pound;","thousands_sep":",","decimal_point":".","siteLocale":"en_GB","dateFormat":"m\/d\/Y","startOfWeek":"1","of":"of","previousMonth":"Previous Month","nextMonth":"Next Month","months":["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"],"monthsShort":["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"],"weekdays":["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"],"weekdaysShort":["Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat"],"weekdaysMin":["Su","Mo","Tu","We","Th","Fr","Sa"],"currency_symbol":"","beforeForm":"","beforeFields":"","afterFields":"","afterForm":""};form.fields=[{"objectType":"Field","objectDomain":"fields","editActive":false,"order":999,"label":"Commission Amount","type":"textbox","key":"commission_amount_1589829372049","label_pos":"above","required":1,"default":"","placeholder":"","container_class":"","element_class":"","input_limit":"","input_limit_type":"characters","input_limit_msg":"Character(s) left","manual_key":false,"admin_label":"","help_text":"","mask":"","custom_mask":"","custom_name_attribute":"","personally_identifiable":"","value":"","drawerDisabled":false,"id":5,"beforeField":"","afterField":"","parentType":"textbox","element_templates":["textbox","input"],"old_classname":"","wrap_template":"wrap"},{"objectType":"Field","objectDomain":"fields","editActive":false,"order":9999,"type":"submit","label":"Submit","processing_label":"Processing","container_class":"","element_class":"","key":"submit_1589829400950","id":6,"beforeField":"","afterField":"","value":"","label_pos":"above","parentType":"textbox","element_templates":["submit","button","input"],"old_classname":"","wrap_template":"wrap-no-label"}];nfForms.push(form);</script>
```

How do I display a form on the admin pages which has submission storage?

How would I enqueue the correct form scripts into the admin scripts?

Comment: The reason your form not displayed is that Ninja Forms plugin enqueues its scripts and styles using `wp_equeue_script()` function, and `wp_enqueue_scripts` action doesn't fire on admin pages. Scripts for admin pages should be enqueued using `admin_enqueue_scripts()` function instead. I don't know is there a workaround for that or not, but if you clarify your question like "how to include scripts enqueued with `wp_equeue_script()` function on admin pages", maybe somebody could tell you something about it, or is it possible at all.